# React HOC wrapper

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I am not sure if I am doing this right but I want to make a hoc that will display components based on if the user is admin. This is my HOC:

```
export const WithUser = (Component) => (props) => {
  if (props.admin) {
    return <Component {...props} />;
  }

  return null;
};
```

There is an error when I use it `Functions are not valid as a React child.` It doesnt make sense to me.

I want to use it like this:

```
<WithUser admin>
   <button>Hi</button>
</WithUser>
```

But I get that error. Maybe Im not using HOCs correctly. I just want to wrap components that the user need to be an admin to view

Comment: Not sure this answers your question but with hooks you can just do like this  `{admin && (<button>Hi</button>)}`, You can replace button with any Component you want

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look [HOC document](https://zh-hant.reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) from react official website

modify your code to this:

```
// admin prop should be obtained from within WithUser or other places such as redux store or react context
export const WithUser = (Component) => (props) => {
  if (props.admin) {
    return <Button {...props} />;
  }

  return null;
};

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <button>Hi</button>
  }
}

export default WithUser(Button)
```

Comment: I dont want to have to define the Button component again. I just want to wrap any component then display it based on if admin

Comment: You should, a higher-order component is a function that takes a component and returns a new component. if you want to use HOC, so you have to define a component if you want to use. you can't use a HOC directly like your example code

Comment: the official documents explains very clear, you can read more...

Answer (score 0):

`WithUser` **is not a component**.  It is a function that takes a component and returns a modified component.  That's what a Higher-Order-Component (HOC) is.

---

You *can* write a component that does what you want with your desired syntax:

```
<WithUser admin>
   <button>Hi</button>
</WithUser>
```

But it won't be an HOC.  Instead you want to use the [`children` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx) to access the child JSX elements and conditionally render them.

```
export const WithUser = ({admin, children}) => {
  return admin ? <>{children}</> : null;
};
```